# How can user send message to his Facebook friend via mobile application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, lua, coronasdk

I write mobile application with Corona SDK.

I want that user that logged with Facebook (I know how to implement user's Facebook login and user's Facebook request for his friends list) could send private Facebook message from application to his friend.

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You can use Corona's [facebook.request](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/request.html) API method to issue calls to Facebook's [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), but there is no API access to send private messages to other users.

Your options are listed in [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/4061298/295262).

Comment: as @SatheeshJM saa=id below, he can use the facebook send dialog, which is a perfect option since he doesn't have to develop the messenger screens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: Sorry I downvoted your answer and now that I want to upvote it again it's not possible anymore. I didn't realize the solution of SatheeshJM is partial only: you cannot have a conversation, you cans just send à link :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Facebook Send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)!

Use the link mentioned under the **Direct URL Example** to open a [Web Popup](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/showWebPopup.html) or [Web View](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html)

Comment: This is not available for mobile devices as of 4/21/13.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @SatheeshJM, you just saved me time and frustration :)